# How to look at received messages from a specific date in AWS SQS? (or alternatively last received today)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a dead letter queue in AWS, and few days ago I had about 30k messages in it. Today I made some changes in a service that work with this queue, and I see now there is in the queue 33K messages, and I want to look only on the messages from today, is that possible?

Usually I would right click, "view/delete messages" and click on start pulling, but I dont see the ones from today at the top and there is a limit of how much can I pull...

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware this is not possible, short of pulling all of the messages out of the queue and throwing them all back in.

If I'm ever in doubt for things like this I'll usually go to the API docs and see if there's any possible parameter I can use:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html

In this case, I don't see anything that'd help with what you're looking to do.

Filtering out/sorting items in the queue is not really what `SQS` was designed for. It's purely meant to be used as a queue where you insert things in it and then pull them out (in either the standard `SQS` form or `SQS FIFO` form).